# How can I prevent my widget from updating on the first run?

Tags: java, android, android-widget

I'm trying to create a simple widget and have extended the `AppWidgetProvider` and overridden the the `onUpdate` method.

When I place the widget on the homescreen, it opens up the associated settings activity that I've defined in the XML. This seems to be logical and resonable behaviour but I can see that it also calls `onUpdate` method. Since I haven't yet configured my widget, the code in my `onUpdate` method fails.

Is it normal behaviour for a widget to call the the `onUpdate` method the moment the widget is place on the homescreen? ...or am I doing something wrong and it should only be called after the settings activity has exited?

Is there way I can check on my `onUpdate` method that the widget has not been invoked before the configuration has been done i.e. the settings activity has finished?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is normal behaviour for a widget to call the the onUpdate method the moment the widget is place on the homescreen. But to solve your problem you can add complete block of code of onUpdate inside a if block which will be executed only if configuration has been done . **To do so you can use a staic Boolean Flag** which will be `True` if setting has been done else  `false`.

you have to do something like this

```
public class ConfigActivity extends Activity {

Static Boolean flag=false;
App_setting()
 {
flag=true;
//rest of configuration code
}
}
```

and your onUpdate like this

```
@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager,
        int[] appWidgetIds) {
if(ConfigActivity.flag==true){
//block of code
}
```